# use timeit.Timer() to time a function with two arguments in a class

Tags: python, self, timeit

I am trying to use timeit to get the run time of one of the function in the 
with two arguments, but I keep getting error: cannot import name make_heap()
    class queueHeap():
    def make_heap(self, alist):
                i = len(alist)//2
                self.currentSize = len(alist)
                self.heapList = [0] + alist[:]
                while (i > 0):
                        self.swapDown(i)
                        i = i - 1

```
for num in range(1, 100, 10) :
        L = []
        binaryHeap = queueHeap()
        for i in range(1, num):
                randomElement = random.randint(1, 100)
                L.append(randomElement)
                time_MakeHeap = timeit.Timer('make_heap(self, L)', 'from __main__ import make_heap, self, L')
                print("n=%s: %s" % (num,  time_MakeHeap.timeit(1)))
```

Comment: the class is queueHeap():

Comment: Please fix the code formatting in the question. As it stands it's completely impossible to understand what it does, since all indentation is messed up and part of it isn't in a code block.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `__main__` refers to the current *module*, not the current *scope*.

For example if you have a `testing.py` file with:

```
class Test:
    def method(self):
        import __main__
        print(vars(__main__))

Test().method()
```

The output of running it is:

```
$python3 testing.py 
{'__file__': 'testing.py', '__cached__': None, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f5e8a027518>, '__doc__': None, '__spec__': None, '__name__': '__main__', '__package__': None, 'Test': <class '__main__.Test'>}
```

Note:

1. `self` isn't in the dictionary returned
2. `method` isn't either
3. Only module-level variables are in there

so you *cannot* access `self` and `method` like that. In fact, the whole thing seems really bad design. Why do you want to profile a class inside one of its methods? Just use an instance:

```
my_instance = MyClass()
result = timeit.Timer('my_instance.the_method()', 'from __main__ import my_instance').timeit(1)
```